# How to display Notification from a LaunchDaemon process?

Tags: applescript, notifications, launchd

I have a LaunchDaemon process that needs to run as root user. The process internally calls `osascript` to display some notifications. Notifications display fine when the process is run manually without LaunchDaemon but when run with `launchctl` I get the following error when it tries to display a notification.

```
2020-07-05 21:39:02.350 osascript[48399:326313] NSNotificationCenter connection invalid
2020-07-05 21:45:19.023 osascript[48688:330683] NSNotificationCenter connection invalid
2020-07-05 21:45:19.023 osascript[48688:330683] Connection to notification center invalid. ServerConnectionFailure: 1 invalidated: 0
2020-07-05 21:45:19.023 osascript[48688:330683] Connection to notification center invalid. ServerConnectionFailure: 1 invalidated: 0
```

From searching on the Internet I have an impression that since LaunchDaemon processes can run without a user logged in, notifications cannot be shown. Is this correct? How do I workaround this?

I am on macOS Catalina 10.15.3.

Comment: Good assumption - the user interface is launched only when a user is loggged in and attaching to that might require using an API and permissions. We’re debating having a second task to run in user space so it can watch the log file and notify to get around this. Hopefully someone has a better idea. Great question.